# what are the CAA rules on eye surgery?

Tags: medical, flight-attendant, caa-uk-regulations

I've been assessed and hired as cabin crew member by Easyjet in UK, on the 26th april I will have my medical assessment.
2 weeks ago I did a PRK refractive laser surgery for myopia correction. Today I've got another eyes examination that certified that there is not a refractive error anymore, that my visual acuity is better than aviation standards, that i'm not experiencing post-operative complitations or problematic visual effects as ghosting or halos or glares and so on... So actually all my eye functionality are giving great results.
Axa health medical requested me this report to send to CAA to be analysed and decide if I'm fit to fly and procede with my face-to-face medical assessment.
My worries concern not about the eyes visual standards but the TIME. 
Could CAA reject me for a matter of time, even if from my eye surgery date to the start of training pass exactly 2 monthes?
Could CAA complain about a full eye report, even if completely successfull, that has been provided after 2 post operative weeks?
I know is trivial but I would be gratefull if someone could help me... Thanks